# Try to port intall gcc47, Error: Dependency 'ld64' not found

Tags: macos, gcc, macports

Try to install gcc47 on osx 10.6.8  but got the following error:

```
 sudo port install gcc47
--->  Computing dependencies for gcc47
Error: Dependency 'ld64' not found.
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: same here on 10.7.3 ... with a fresh macports install

Comment: really curious about what is "ld64"?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's still there at /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/devel/ld64 However, the Portfile seems so buggy that port index can't parse it. I installed llvm-3.0 first and then edited the Portfile, commenting out the following lines

```
#if {![variant_isset llvm29] && ![variant_isset llvm30] && ![variant_isset llvm31]} {
#    default_variants +llvm30
#}

#set llvm_version {}
#variant llvm29 conflicts llvm30 llvm31 description {Use llvm-2.9 for libLTO} {
#    set llvm_version        2.9
#    depends_lib-append      port:llvm-${llvm_version}
#}

#variant llvm30 conflicts llvm29 llvm31 description {Use llvm-3.0 for libLTO} {
set llvm_version        3.0
#    depends_lib-append      port:llvm-${llvm_version}
#}

#variant llvm31 conflicts llvm29 llvm30 description {Use llvm-3.1 for libLTO} {
#    set llvm_version        3.1
#    depends_lib-append      port:llvm-${llvm_version}
#}
```

After this, running "sudo portindex" cleared the issue. Finally I was able to install ld64 and gcc47.

Comment: hello, can't find /macports/ how do i find out the path? and how to install llvm3? thanks!

Comment: /opt/local/var/macports & sudo port install llvm-3.0

Comment: worked like intended by FFox: Change the Portfile. run "sudo portindex" in your macports rep: probably "/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/devel"... cleared the issue for me...

Answer (score 1):

The following commands solved my problem. Since the error was only for ld64 and cctools ports in my case.

```
sudo port clean ld64 cctools
sudo port install gcc47
```

Answer (score 0):

The ld64 package has been pulled from macports as of today:
http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=ld64
It was still available yesterday though.

However, the package did not build correctly when I tried it yesterday because of build errors with llvm-3.0.

Answer (score 0):

The ld64 package is back on the index but it fails to build :-(

First there is a xcodebuild issue with the license agreement. I fixed it with the tip from [1](https://github.com/kokoabim/iOSOpenDev/wiki/Troubleshoot). But now there's a build failure because of an undeclared identifier.

Comment: I just did a `selfupdate` and now the `ld64` package build correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command; seems working for now.

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install gcc47
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you get this problem. I am also encountering this problem after I upgrade my system to **Mavericks**. After check the **main.log** file, I found that the error is because the build cannot find . Then, I **install the newest version Xcode Command Line Tools** , it works! Hope my experience is helpful to you.